# Syntax error in mysql init file when trying to flush privileges

Tags: mysql

I'm following the directions for windows at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

I'm trying to reset the root password. So I created a text file called pwreset.txt and inside it I wrote

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('poo') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The docs say "Write the UPDATE and FLUSH statements each on a single line. The UPDATE statement resets the password for all root accounts, and the FLUSH statement tells the server to reload the grant tables into memory so that it notices the password change."

Okay then I start the server with `mysqld-nt --defaults-file=... --init-file=...\\pwreset.txt --console` and I get

```
ERROR: 1064 You have made an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FLUSH PRIVILEGES' at line 1
```

But I copied that syntax almost exactly from the docs! The database version is 5.0.80 Enterprise Pro Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code here,

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('poo') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

is not each written on a single line.

Try

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('poo') WHERE User='root'; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: The `;` character sufficiently indicates a new query. Adding a newline won't change anything.

Comment: It normally does in terms of queries, I am not sure if that still applies to init scripts, I am assuming that as the instructions specifically state they need to be on separate lines, that may have something to do with it

Comment: Oh it asks for each on a single line. I misread it! I thought it was asking for both on the same line.

Comment: just came across this issue. It is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_init_file